# using buttons to switch frames in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I am creating a iOS App in Flash CS5.  The initial screen will have a selection of buttons.  Once a button is selected, the app should clear the screen of all buttons and text then draw a number of rectangles using some code that pulls data from an XML document.

I guess my overall question is how to use buttons to switch frames and how do I create completely seperate frames to show different context.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to give you buttons instance names. Then you can use this code to move to any frame on the timeline:

```
// button is the instance name
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
function onButtonClick(evt:MouseEvent):void{
  gotoAndStop(10);
}
```

This would go to frame 10. I recommend you use framelables so that you can say things like :

```
gotoAndStop("page2");
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  I am just getting started with Flash Apps.  Do you know of any online resources that have a sample app similar to what I am trying to do that I can download and pull apart?  This always seems to work best for me.